# Beginner Grid With Bootstrap - Rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Having a problem with getting the items of the following code vertically aligned with bootstrap 4. Before the addition of the row they are all stacked but revert to being horizontally in-line when the "row" or "row align-items-start" classes are added.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-start"> 
        <h1></h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="image URL">
            <button class="btn btn-dark">
                Submit!
            </button>
        </form>
        <a href="/">Go Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. What's the issue after removing the `row` class?

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to style it so that each element sits ontop of one another, which is the case before I add the row styling. One row is added, the H1 sits on the left, with the form on the right directly beside it.

Comment: not understand why you can't remove row

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a column, see example.

```
​<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1></h1>
            <form action="" method="POST">
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="image URL">
        <button class="btn btn-dark">
            Submit!
        </button>
    </form>
        <a href="/">Go Back</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly I swear this was the first thing I tried and didn't see it change! Thank you!!